# Storing resultant cell value from an addition and then adding it to new results every time

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a model in Excel in which a cell computes the sum of two cells and keeps adding to the value every time the two cells on which it is dependent change values. For example,

If,

A + B = C

Then,

Instance 1: -> 5 + 5 = 10

Instance 2: -> 4 + 3 = 17

Instance 3: -> 2 + 3 = 22

and so on...

I believe this can be achieved through a VB script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you only need to put the following code in the worksheet code pane:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Range("A1:A2"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Range("B1") = Range("B1") + WorksheetFunction.sum(Range("A1:A2"))
End Sub
```

of course you have to change:

- all "A1:A2" occurrences to your actual cells to sum address
- all "B1" occurrences to your actual cell holding the running sum address

Comment: That's +1 for you. I wrote for debug.print and forgot to refactor for then using a worksheet cell to hold the result :-) Dammit

Comment: thanks @QHarr. Well, the resultant cell is explicitly quoted by the OP, so I went with it

Comment: You are right. I didn't read properly and when did, re-wrote but completely forgot I was now working with a range to store the value :-)

Comment: Hey thanks, the code works. Now,  if I want to add a condition for the summation, like, if C1 = 1, then A1+A2 = B1, how would I do that?

Comment: Hey sorry about that. Did not notice. Have done that.

Comment: @SharatPrakash, I can't understand your new  _condition_: you may want to give more details

Comment: @DisplayName Suppose there is an If condition. If C1 = 1, then do the sum - A1 + A2 = B1. So whenever cell C1 = 1, the code should do the same and keep storing the values as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the running total in a Public variable (`total`). Initialize this as the workbook opens, using the workbook_open event, to the sum of the two cells of interest. Then use a worksheet_change event to monitor changes to those two cells and, if either changes, add their new value to the existing value of `total`. I have used cell `C1` to show the running total.

**In a standard module:**

```
Option Explicit

Public total As Long
Public targetCell As Range
```

**In the ThisWorkbook code pane**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set targetCell = .Range("C1")

        total = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("A1:B1"))
        targetCell = total

    End With

End Sub
```

**In the worksheet code pane where the cells to monitor are**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        total = total + Target
        targetCell = total
    End If

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then
        total = total + Target
        targetCell = total
    End If

End Sub
```

Or correctly do what @DisplayName has done! I wrote this initially for a Debug.Print of total (not writing to cell) and forgot to re-factor.